# A similar tool of odk but with search and retrieve data features

Tags: odk

We are working on survey's using ODK, by creating xls files and transform it into forms, and then we collect data offline.

When employees comeback from the field, they upload data.

What we need now is that they work online from the field, so they can search a specific ID or name, and see the data existing before adding new data.

What I mean is that we need to let them search the database by specific field, and that is not available in odk.

We upload data to ONA then the data are cleaned on the laptop and the searches are done on the laptop too.

Is there a tool that do that process ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the closest you can get with existing tools is this: https://help.ona.io/faq/filtered-datasets

If you use Enketo (webforms), when the source dataset is updated (via new submissions) the webform will also be automatically updated (may require page refresh and there will be a delay). You could use both offline-capable or online-only webforms with this reference to external data and query it with select_one_from_file, select_multiple_from_file (in XLSForm terminology), or with pulldata, or with regular XPath.

Comment: If I want to connect to a server via IP and query data from it ?

Comment: I believe you cannot specify an IP address (nor URL), but best to check with Ona.